# Field 'mobile' expected a number but got ['2222222', '2222222']

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

**This is Error showing**

```
TypeError at /page
Field 'mobile' expected a number but got ['22222', '3333'].
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/page
Django Version: 4.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
Field 'mobile' expected a number but got ['22222', '3333'].
```

**While Submitting Form This error occurs.**
I am trying to submit form of same name twice simultaneously to same model

**Views.py**

```
def page(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        description = request.POST['description']
        price = request.POST['price']
        name = request.POST.getlist('name')
        mobile = request.POST.getlist('mobile')

        pay = bill(description=description,price=price)
        pay.save()

        
        mypayee = payee(billId=pay,name=name,mobile=mobile)
        mypayee.save()

    return render(request, 'split_app/page.html')
```

**this model**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class bill(models.Model):
    price = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
        
class payee(models.Model):
    billId = models.ForeignKey(bill,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='persons')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mobile = models.IntegerField()
```

**this is image of HTML FORM generated using javascript**
***[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P27TM.png)***

** This is how I am submitting data with form having same form twice of same name(name & mobile) **

**HTML generate**

```
<div class="container my-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">ADD NEW BILL</button>
        <form action="/page" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <label for="discription" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">DESCRIPTION:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="text" name="description" id="discription" placeholder="Bill For.." />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <label for="price" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">BILL PRICE:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <input type="number" name="price" id="price" title="only numbers allowed"
                        placeholder="&#x20B9" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
                <label for="person" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">SPLIT IN:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="increment()">+</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="payeesbtn">ADD PAYEE:</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="decrement()">-</button>

                    <div class="container my-3" id="addpayees"></div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
let x = 1;
function increment() {
        
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'container my-3';
    div.idName = 'x';

    
    div.innerHTML = `<h5>payee ${x}</h5>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name:</th>
                                <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Mobile:</th>
                                <td><input type="number" name="mobile"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <input type="button" value="-" onclick="decrement(this)" />
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="decrement(this)">-</button>`;

    document.getElementById("addpayees").appendChild(div);
      
    x++;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `payee.mobile` field is defined as an `IntegerField`, but in your view function you are calling:

```py
mobile = request.POST.getlist('mobile')
```

which produces a list of values. Then you do this:

```py
mypayee = payee(billId=pay,name=name,mobile=mobile)
```

That is what the error tells you. You are trying to create a `payee` instance and assign a list to the integer field.

**PS:**

If you want to create **two separate** instances of `payee` with both those values `['22222', '3333']`, you need to do something like:

```py
mypayee1 = payee(billId=pay,name=int(name[0]),mobile=int(mobile[0]))
mypayee2 = payee(billId=pay,name=int(name[1]),mobile=int(mobile[1]))
```

But I am just guessing here.

**PPS:**

If the size of the `name` and `mobile` lists is dynamic, you could loop over them. You did not provide a lot of context, but I assume that those query parameters in the `POST` request will have the same number of items, i.e. the lists will be of the same size. Then you could do something like this:

```py
def page(request):
    ...
    names = request.POST.getlist('name')
    mobiles = request.POST.getlist('mobile')
    pay = bill(description=description,price=price)
    pay.save()
    for name, mobile in zip(names, mobiles):
        mypayee = payee(billId=pay,name=name,mobile=int(mobile))
        mypayee.save()
```

If you don't care about the `pre_save` and `post_save` signals, you could [create them in bulk](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) like this: (check the docs for caveats!)

```py
def page(request):
    ...
    names = request.POST.getlist('name')
    mobiles = request.POST.getlist('mobile')
    pay = bill(description=description,price=price)
    pay.save()
    payee.objects.bulk_create([
        payee(billId=pay,name=name,mobile=int(mobile))
        for name, mobile in zip(names, mobiles)
    ])
```

Either way, at this point I would strongly suggest wrapping the entire affair in a [transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/transactions/) to ensure data integrity.